# Angular Material does not seem to work in StackBlitz

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, stackblitz, angular-material-8

While trying to replicate another issue I am having, I tried to use StackBlitz to replicate.

However Angular Material does not seem to work on StackBlitz.... any advice or ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e4qp5q

#### Update

That link is now in working order. The problem was I didn't include styles import.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`styles.css`

needs a theme, e.g.

`@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';`

See - https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

**Update**

In case any one else lands here with different issues I'll add common issues getting Stackblitz to work with Angular Materials:

Note that the each component has an up-to-date stackblitz - the link for each  is on the **Examples** tab on the far right for each component
e.g https://material.angular.io/components/slider/examples
[image]

**Checklist**

1. Check Theme is on `styles.css`
2. Check if `hammer.js` is required (see any note in italics on API tab), if so add `import 'hammerjs';` to `polyfills.ts`. Note in your application you will do so in your app's entry point (e.g. src/main.ts). See the **Getting Started** guide on the website https://material.angular.io/guides
3. Make sure to import `BrowserAnimationsModule`
4. Make sure to import relevant modules for the particular component from material eg `import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';`. The examples on the website import everthing en masse. My strategy when I only want to import exactly what is required has been to import the module shown on the API tab and then google the error message e.g. `mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl` and find stackoverflow answer to know `MatInputModule` is missing.

Answer (score 7):

You need to import a theme in your application. Add this line to `styles.css`:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-4-include-a-theme

Andrew Allen was faster :)

Comment: That was indeed a close run xD